# RDLC report from MySQL formating issue

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, rdlc

I need to create a RDLC report from a MySQL db that needs to show timecard info per user, per day between 2 dates (user choice) Like this eg:

UserFirstName UserLastName

2019-01-11 InTimeStamp OutTimeStamp TimeSpan

2019-01-12 InTimeStamp OutTimeStamp TimeSpan

2019-01-13 InTimeStamp OutTimeStamp TimeSpan

2019-01-14 InTimeStamp OutTimeStamp TimeSpan

Total: totalTimeForThePeriod

I need this for every user within the dates provided by the user.
I have already setup the HR report page and the date choice (works perfectly) but I can`t seem to be able to format my RDLC report to show the info as requested. How can I seperate the data to acheive this? My dataset gets all the data from the db (query works great). All I need to do now is to show it properly in the report. Any ideas on how I can acheive this?

I've tried using a simple table but that does'nt work.
I also tried a matrix, but I can't seem to show the data as requested.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to go one by one creating your rows. Also have your Grouping window open, so you can see your grouping. First right click where you want your first row and click Add Group -> Parent Group. In the Group by: drop down select a UserFirstName. Then it should add UserFirstName to your grid. To the right of it add UserLastName. Next in your grouping window under Row Groups click the drop down arrow on (UserFirstName) and click Add Group->Child Group. This time group by [TimeStampDate]. This will create a new row under your original row that is a sub group of UserFirstName. Add in the addition data in this new row. Lastly in the grouping window under Row Groups click the drop down on TimeStampDate then click Add Total->After. This should add a total row under the TimeStampDate row. You can change the [Sum(TimeStampDate )] to [totalTimeForThePeriod]. This should get you what you need.

```
[UserFirstName]     [UserLastName]      
[TimeStampDate] [InTimeStamp]   [OutTimeStamp]  [TimeSpan]
Total:  [totalTimeForThePeriod]
```

[image: image of excel sheet]

I struggled with the same issue for hours, so I hope this helps!